# \foreach not behaving in axis environment

Tags: pgfplots, loops, foreach

Am hesitant to ask yet one more embarrassing question, but I can't seem to see the problem with the `\foreach` in the MWE. It should produce several horizontal lines but only produces the one with the `yValue` as specified in the `\newcommand{\yValue}{0.3}`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcommand{\yValue}{0.3}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
 ymin=0,
 ymax=1,
 xmin=0,
 xmax=1,
]

\foreach \yValue in {0.00,0.1,...,1.00} {
    \draw [red] (axis cs:0,\yValue) -- (axis cs:1,\yValue);
}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\draw [red] foreach \yValue in {0.00,0.1,...,1.00} {(axis cs:0,\yValue) -- (axis cs:1,\yValue)};` does what you want.

Comment: Take a look at page 910 and 911 of the manual; it looks like you can use `\foreach` (or `foreach`) inside of a path, but you can't put a path inside of `\foreach`. At least, I assume the latter is true, since it doesn't work. The manual doesn't explicitly say that.

Comment: @Adam: That would be a fine solution to post for the MWE given, but I actually have to do more than one thing in the `\foreach` so not sure it'll work for my specific case.  Also, Page 909 shows an example of what I am trying to use.

Comment: Ah, the answer seems to be at pages 470 and 471 of the [`pgfplots` documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

According to pages 470-471 of the [`pgfplots` documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf):

(*Note:* in `pgfplots` documentation v1.17, the page range has changed to 544-545.)

> Keep in mind that inside of an axis environment, all loop constructions (including custom loops, `\foreach` and `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped`) need to be handled with care: loop arguments can only be used in places where they are immediately evaluated; but `pgfplots` postpones the evaluation of many macros. For example, to loop over something and to generate axis descriptions of the form `\node at (axis cs:\i,0.5)....`, the loop macro `\i` will be evaluated in `\end{axis}` – but at that time, the loop is over and its value is lost. The correct way to handle such an application is to *expand* the loop variable *explicitly*.

Thus, you need to do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
 ymin=0,
 ymax=1,
 xmin=0,
 xmax=1,
]

\foreach \yValue in {0.00,0.1,...,1.00} {
    \edef\temp{\noexpand\draw [red] (axis cs:0,\yValue) -- (axis cs:1,\yValue);}
    \temp
}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Edit

As [@percusee points out in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170664/foreach-not-behaving-in-axis-environment/170670#comment393042_170670), you can also use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach`. This is different from `\foreach` because, according to page 471 of the [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf):

> the `\x` would not be expanded whereas `#1` is.

That is to say, it does exactly what is needed to handle the fact that `pgfplots` doesn't evaluate loop macros until `\end{axis}`.

Thus, you can also do:

```
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0.00,0.1,...,1.00}{
    \draw [red] (axis cs:0,#1) -- (axis cs:1,#1);
}
```

Note that the syntax is slightly different. `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` uses `#1`, just like a `\newcommand` would, instead of allowing you to name your own variable.

Comment: Great. Thanks. Am surprised that I have not encountered this problem until today, at least I don't recall that I have -- just in case someone comes up an answer of mine that uses this :-).

Comment: `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` does this for you automatically.

Comment: @percusse Thanks for the tip. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: How can we use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` in a nested way?

Comment: @bkarpuz Unfortunately, you can't. From the [`pgfplots` documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf): "you can't nest this command yet (since it does not introduce protection by scopes)".

Comment: Note that `pgfplotsinvokeforeach` solution only work if you don't in addition define your own macros inside the loop, as they're postponed (read the first half of the answer carefully). For example see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/390115/250119.

Answer (score 9):

I ran into a similar problem and the answers above didn't work for me.  However, I realized that you often want to use `foreach` *inside* an `axis` environment because you want to have access to the `axis cs` coordinate system.  I came up with the following workaround which I show here for the original MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ymin=0, ymax=1, xmin=0, xmax=1]
    \coordinate (O) at (axis cs:0,0);
    \coordinate (X) at (axis cs:1,0);
    \coordinate (Y) at (axis cs:0,1);
  \end{axis}  
  \begin{scope}[x={($(X)-(O)$)}, y={($(Y)-(O)$)}, shift={(O)}]
    \foreach \y in {0, 0.1, ..., 1} {
      \draw[red] (0,\y) -- (1,\y);
    }
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The idea obviously is that you "recreate" the coordinate system in the `scope` after leaving the `axis` environment.  This also works with 3D coordinates.  (Note that in newer versions of `pgfplots` you don't need the `axis cs:` prefix anymore.)

Comment: Not sure who robust this solution is. Probably some options to `tikzpicture` or `axis` environment will break this, bit does seem to work for the given MWE.

Comment: @PeterGrill I've actually used this trick for quite complicated situations - for example, I mixed 3D mesh plots with blocks inserted by a `foreach` loop - and it worked fine so far.