# Problems using `\foreach`to parametrize a sequence of graphs in Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, foreach

I want to create a series of overlapping graphs in a Beamer slide, with little variations between them.

I have code that works as expected in one case, but fails in other, and I don't understand why, so I'm asking for help.

The MWE is:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{default}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

% Math
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bigints}

% Figures
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
  compat = 1.12,
  tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,
    assume math mode=true,
    set decimal separator={,}
  },
}

% Units
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  output-decimal-marker = {,},
  exponent-product=\!\cdot\!,
  per-mode = symbol,
  group-separator = {.},
  output-complex-root = \ensuremath{\mathrm{j}},
  binary-units,
  retain-unity-mantissa = false,
  retain-explicit-plus = true,
  range-phrase = { a },
}


\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\setbeamercovered{highly dynamic}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Showing the problem}
      % Definition of some parametrization data
      \def\Data{1/0,2/30,3/45,4/60,5/90,6/120,7/180}
      \def\Tx{2}%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\fx}{1/\Tx}%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\wx}{2*pi*\fx}%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\N}{2}%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=80pt]
        \tikzset{
          every pin/.style={fill=yellow!40!white,rectangle,rounded corners=3pt,font=\small,inner sep=1pt},
      dot/.style={fill=black,circle,scale=0.3},
    }
    \begin{axis}[
      name=eixos,
      title={\small{Voltage and current}},
      width=.8\textwidth,
      height=.4\textheight,
      xmin=0,
      xmax=\N*\Tx,
      axis x line=middle,
      xtick={\N},
      xticklabels={$T_x$},
      xlabel={$t$},
      x label style={at={(axis description cs:1,0)},anchor=west},
      ymin=-1.25,
      ymax=1.25,
      ytick={-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1},
      yticklabels={},
      ylabel={${\color{red}v(t)}\:,\:{\color{blue}i(t)}$},
      ylabel near ticks,
      axis y line=left,
      y axis line style={-},
      clip=false,
    ]
%%%%%%% This code works as expected
    \only<1>{\def\Ang{0}}
    \only<2>{\def\Ang{30}}
    \only<3>{\def\Ang{45}}
    \only<4>{\def\Ang{60}}
    \only<5>{\def\Ang{90}}
    \only<6>{\def\Ang{120}}
    \only<7>{\def\Ang{180}}
    \addplot[domain=0:\N*\Tx,samples=50,red,line width=1pt] {cos(deg(\wx*x))};
    \addplot[domain=0:\N*\Tx,samples=50,blue,line width=1pt] {0.7*cos(deg(\wx*x)-\Ang)};
    \draw[-latex,red,line width=0.7pt,font=\tiny] (\Tx,0) -- (\Tx,1) 
      node[midway,left,fill=yellow!40!white,inner sep=0pt] {$V_p$};
    \draw[-latex,blue,line width=0.7pt,font=\tiny] (\Ang*\Tx/360,0) -- (\Ang*\Tx/360,0.7) 
      node[midway,right,fill=yellow!40!white,inner sep=0pt] {$I_p$};
    \node[font=\tiny] at (axis cs:1,1) {$\Delta\phi=\SI{\Ang}{\degree}$};

%%%%%%% This code doesn't work, although similar code in second graph works OK
%         \foreach \Slide/\Ang in \Data {
%           \only<\Slide> {
%             \addplot[domain=0:\N*\Tx,samples=50,red,line width=1pt] {cos(deg(\wx*x))};
%             \addplot[domain=0:\N*\Tx,samples=50,blue,line width=1pt] {0.7*cos(deg(\wx*x)-\Ang)};
%             \draw[-latex,red,line width=0.7pt,font=\tiny] (\Tx,0) -- (\Tx,1) 
%               node[midway,left,fill=yellow!40!white,inner sep=0pt] {$V_p$};
%             \draw[-latex,blue,line width=0.7pt,font=\tiny] (\Ang*\Tx/360,0) -- (\Ang*\Tx/360,0.7) 
%               node[midway,right,fill=yellow!40!white,inner sep=0pt] {$I_p$};
%             \node[font=\tiny] at (axis cs:1,1) {$\Delta\phi=\SI{\Ang}{\degree}$};
%           }
%         }
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{
      every pin/.style={fill=yellow!40!white,rectangle,rounded corners=3pt,font=\small,inner sep=1pt},
      dot/.style={fill=black,circle,scale=0.3},
    }
    \begin{axis}[
      name=eixos,
      title={\small{Instantaneous power}},
      width=.8\textwidth,
      height=.4\textheight,
      xmin=0,
      xmax=\N*\Tx,
      axis x line=middle,
      xtick={2},
      xticklabels={$T_x$},
      xlabel={$t$},
      x label style={at={(axis description cs:1,0)},anchor=west},
      ymin=-1.1,
      ymax=1.1,
      ytick={-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1},
      yticklabels={},
      ylabel={\color{violet}$p(t)$},
      ylabel near ticks,
      axis y line=left,
      y axis line style={-},
      tick label style={/pgf/number format/use comma},
      clip=false,
    ]
    \foreach \Slide/\Ang in \Data {
      \only<\Slide>{
        \addplot[domain=0:\N*\Tx,samples=100,violet,line width=1pt] {cos(deg(\wx*x))*0.7*cos(deg(\wx*x)-\Ang)};
        \addplot[orange,dashed,line width=1pt] coordinates {(0,0.35*cos(\Ang) (4,0.35*cos(\Ang)};
      }
    }
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This produces a series of slides, one of them being like:
[image]

As you can see in the code, the **second** graph is produced using

```
\foreach \Slide/\Ang in \Data {
  \only<\Slide>{
    \addplot[domain=0:\N*\Tx,samples=100,violet,line width=1pt] {cos(deg(\wx*x))*0.7*cos(deg(\wx*x)-\Ang)};
    \addplot[orange,dashed,line width=1pt] coordinates {(0,0.35*cos(\Ang) (4,0.35*cos(\Ang)};
  }
}
```

With `\Data` being defined above as:

```
\def\Data{1/0,2/30,3/45,4/60,5/90,6/120,7/180}
```

and this works as expected. But if I try to draw the **first** graph using the same technique, i.e:

```
    \foreach \Slide/\Ang in \Data {
      \only<\Slide> {
        \addplot[domain=0:\N*\Tx,samples=50,red,line width=1pt] {cos(deg(\wx*x))};
        \addplot[domain=0:\N*\Tx,samples=50,blue,line width=1pt] {0.7*cos(deg(\wx*x)-\Ang)};
        \draw[-latex,red,line width=0.7pt,font=\tiny] (\Tx,0) -- (\Tx,1) 
          node[midway,left,fill=yellow!40!white,inner sep=0pt] {$V_p$};
        \draw[-latex,blue,line width=0.7pt,font=\tiny] (\Ang*\Tx/360,0) -- (\Ang*\Tx/360,0.7) 
          node[midway,right,fill=yellow!40!white,inner sep=0pt] {$I_p$};
        \node[font=\tiny] at (axis cs:1,1) {$\Delta\phi=\SI{\Ang}{\degree}$};
      }
    }
```

I get a lot of compilation errors, being the first one:
    ! Undefined control sequence.
     \Ang 
                    *\Tx /360,0
    l.145 \end{frame}

and the last `\draw` and `\node` commands are not executed correctly.

I've managed to overcome the problem by getting rid of the `\foreach` statement and using `\only` environments to set different values of `\Ang` on each slide:

```
    \only<1>{\def\Ang{0}}
    \only<2>{\def\Ang{30}}
    \only<3>{\def\Ang{45}}
    \only<4>{\def\Ang{60}}
    \only<5>{\def\Ang{90}}
    \only<6>{\def\Ang{120}}
    \only<7>{\def\Ang{180}}
```

It works, but I can't understand why the `\foreach` solution works in the second case but not in first one.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: Seems that the problem is located in `node`statements...

Comment: Maybe this question gets easier to answer, if you try to produce a more minimalistic MWE? I guess with some simple shapes and not so many overlays it might be easier to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: @samcarter. Sorry for the long MWE. I left it as is because I thought the problem might be related to obscure interactions with beamer overlays. But now it seems not. See my next comment.

Comment: After a lot of googling I found this question on StackExchange (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170664/foreach-not-behaving-in-axis-environment) that seems to explain the source of the problem.

Comment: I've found [this other question on StackExchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170664/foreach-not-behaving-in-axis-environment) that explains the problem and gives the reason and some clues. In short, it seems that that inside of an axis environment, all loop constructions (including custom loops, \foreach and \pgfplotsforeachungrouped) need to be handled with care.