# define color in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color

I want to plot funtions and data with own colors using `\definecolor{<name>}{<model>}{<value(s)>}`. If I use this command in `\tikzpicture` it works. But if I use this command in `pgfplots` all defined colors are black. Why?

My Example (not wondering about some calculations - I need that for more complex functions and data plotting):

```
\documentclass[rgb]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{sistyle}

\newcommand{\thetamin}{-90}
\newcommand{\thetamax}{90}
\newcommand{\thetaminplusstep}{-80}

%======================================================================================

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title={Title},title style={text width=8cm,font=\tiny},ylabel={y}, xlabel={x}, legend style={cells={anchor=west}, legend pos=north west, font=\tiny}, xmin=-1, xmax=1, ymin=-1, ymax=1]
        \foreach \i in {\thetamin,\thetaminplusstep,...,\thetamax}{
        \newcount\k
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\k}{\i/\thetamax}
        \newcount\j
        \j=400
        \ifnum\i<0
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\j}{-400*\i/\thetamin+800} 
        \else
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\j}{(-400/\thetamax*\i)+800}
        \fi     
        \definecolor{tmpcolor}{wave}{\j}
    \colorlet{mycolor}[rgb]{tmpcolor}
        \addplot[color=mycolor, mark=none, domain=-1:1,samples=100]{\k*x};
        %\addlegendentry{$\ang{\i}$};
        }   
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {\thetamin,\thetaminplusstep,...,\thetamax}{
        \newcount\k
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\k}{\i/\thetamax*2}
        \newcount\j
        \j=400
        \ifnum\i<0
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\j}{-400*\i/\thetamin+800} 
        \else
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\j}{(-400/\thetamax*\i)+800} 
        \fi     
        \definecolor{tmpcolor}{wave}{\j}
    \colorlet{mycolor}[rgb]{tmpcolor}
        \draw[fill=mycolor] (0,\k) rectangle (1,\k+0.25);
        \draw[black] (2.5,\k+0.15) node {\tiny $\ang{\i}$, wave: \j};
        }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

As result I get:
[image: define color in pgfplots]

I look forward to a useful answer.

anne

Comment: Have you looked at the color maps section of the pgfplots manual? It is relatively easy to define a new color map yourself and then use that in a plot.

Comment: By the way, a completely unrelated comment: You're plotting straight lines with 100 samples each. You can save some computation time if you set `samples=2` instead, and it won't affect the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem caused in `\foreach`, also look at [\foreach not behaving in axis environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170664/foreach-not-behaving-in-axis-environment)

to solve the problem I use (during using colormaps)

```
\edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot[color of colormap={\l}, solid, mark=none,domain=-1:1,samples=100]{\k*x};}
        \temp
```

instead of

```
\addplot[color of colormap={\l}, solid, mark=none,domain=-1:1,samples=100]{\k*x};
```

result, problem solved

[image: colorproblem-solved]

also it should works without colormaps but with `\definecolor`?