# pgfplots - Nodes on polar curve r=1+cos(x)

Tags: pgfplots, polarplot

I want to draw circles as node on polar curve `r=1+cos(x)` with equal intervals. I can draw one node on curve, say for 30 degree, using parametric equation of curve using code below.

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=center,
    axis equal image,
    enlargelimits=true,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$
     ]
    \addplot[data cs=polar,orange,domain=0:360,samples=360,smooth, ultra thick] (x,{1+cos(x)});
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{1+cos(30)};%
    \fill (30:\R) circle (2pt); 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For others nodes, inserting using `\foreach`, I give errors as follows:

```
 \addplot[data cs=polar,orange,domain=0:360,samples=360,smooth, ultra thick] (x,{1+cos(x)});
    \foreach \t in {0,10,20,...,360}
    {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{1+cos(\t)};
    \fill (\t:\R) circle (2pt);
    }
```

---

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\UseTextAccent ...up \@firstofone \let \@curr@enc
\cf@encoding \@use@text@en...
l.21 \end{axis}
```

How can I achive this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170664/foreach-not-behaving-in-axis-environment

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis, thank you. It got it.

Comment: @ferafeza, I added a more concise answer. If you even needed to add labels to each of the markes, I would still try to rely on `pgfplots` tools before falling back on `tikz`'s unrivaled power.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]
By the way, an even more concise way of doing what you want is to rely on another `addplot` with `only marks`, `mark=*`, `black`, and `samples=36` options, as follows.

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=center,
    axis equal image,
    enlargelimits=true,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$
     ]
    \addplot[data cs=polar,orange,domain=0:360,samples=360,smooth, ultra thick] (x,{1+cos(x)});
    \addplot[data cs=polar,domain=0:360,samples=36,mark=*,only marks,black] (x,{1+cos(x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```