# Loop in PGFPlot axis environment / Adding value above data points

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, loops

I have two problems when trying to add the value of a data point above the data point. I am trying to solve this with a for-loop:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \myvalues{{50,50,31,25,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24}}%


\begin{axis}[
    width=\textwidth,
    height=.40\textwidth,
    xlabel={x},
    ylabel={y},
    xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15},
    ytick={20,25,30,35,40,45,50},
    xmajorgrids,
    ymajorgrids,
]
\addplot [black, mark=*, mark options={solid}]
table {%
1 50
2 50
3 31
4 25
5 24
6 24
7 24
8 24
9 24
10 24
11 24
12 24
13 24
14 24
15 24
};

 \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}{
        \pgfmathparse{\myvalues[#1-1]};
    \node at (#1,\pgfmathresult+2){\pgfmathresult};
    }

\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Problems:

- Document compiles without errors, but the nodes don't show up in the plot.
- How can I add an if-statement into the for-loop? For example to change the color of the node to red for the nodes 4 and 12?

Thanks a lot!
 -

Comment: You could have a look at `nodes near coords`. Add `nodes near coords` right after `ymajorgrids,` in the `axis` options and the first point is taken care of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170670/100384) answer for another question (among others).

Summarised: `pgfplots` does not execute the command at the time you think it does, but postpones it. At that point `\pgfmathresult` does not contain the computation result any more. You can, however, force the expansion by defining a temporary macro. Note then in this case, any tikz command (`\node`, `\fill`, `\draw`, ...) will need to be protected by a `\noexpand`.

The following code works:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \myvalues{{50,50,31,25,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24}}%


\begin{axis}[
    width=\textwidth,
    height=.40\textwidth,
    xlabel={x},
    ylabel={y},
    xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15},
    ytick={20,25,30,35,40,45,50},
    xmajorgrids,
    ymajorgrids,
]
\addplot [black, mark=*, mark options={solid}]
table {%
1 50
2 50
3 31
4 25
5 24
6 24
7 24
8 24
9 24
10 24
11 24
12 24
13 24
14 24
15 24
};

 \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}{
        \pgfmathparse{\myvalues[#1-1]};
        \edef\temp{
            \noexpand\node at (#1,\pgfmathresult+2){\pgfmathresult};
        }
        \temp
    }

\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```