# Issue with foreach statement

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using the following code. It compiles fine without the middle `foreach` statement, but fails with `Undefined Control Sequence` with it:

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps,external}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3d,arrows,shapes.geometric}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{150}%


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]

\begin{axis}[
    axis equal,
    axis lines = center,
    width = 16cm,
    height = 16cm,
    xmin=-30,
    xmax=30,
    ymin=-30,
    ymax=30,
    zmin=-30,
    zmax=30,
    view/h=25,
]


    \foreach \t in {20}% generatrices
      \draw[yellow,thin,dashed] (axis cs: {0.75+0.75*cos(\t)},0,     
 {0.75*sin(\t)})
   --(axis cs: {0.75+0.75*cos(\t)},{-33.0},{0.75*sin(\t)});     


    \draw[yellow,thin,densely dotted] (axis cs: 1.5,-33,0)% lower circle
    \foreach \t in {5,10,...,360}
      {--(axis cs: {0.75+0.75*cos(\t)},-33,{0.75*sin(\t)})}--cycle;

    \draw[yellow,thin,densely dotted] (axis cs: 1.5,0,0)% upper circle
    \foreach \t in {5,10,...,360}
       {--(axis cs: {0.75+0.75*cos(\t)},0,{0.75*sin(\t)})}--cycle;



\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I added the {} around the nested `draw` statement. It doesn't seem obvious to me what the problem is.

**EDIT:** MWE provided (bad practice for not doing so!) with `\t` limited to one value but still failing to compile.

Comment: You have to put `;` inside the brace, as the `\draw` is also inside.

Comment: But it failed before those {} were added also.

Comment: But it is a good practice to use braces for `\foreach`! I personally do not use a single semicolon to terminate both `\foreach` and `\draw`. Remember the **goto fail bug** made by Apple?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of it. I re-tested your suggestion. It still falls flat. Without the `\foreach` and hard-coding a single angle compiles well. Do I need a `\draw` outside the `\foreach`?

Comment: Well then... I ran out of ideas. You can either (a) wait for someone else; or (b) complete your code snippet by including both `\documentcalss{xxx}` and `\end{document}`.

Comment: @stars83clouds Can you please add a minimal code wrapper so we can play with it without having to guess? I get `Package tikz Error: Unknown coordinate system 'axis'.`

Comment: `axis cs:` is pgfplots. And https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170664/foreach-not-behaving-in-axis-environment ...

Comment: @Symbol1, egreg - MWE provided above. Bad practice for not doing at the outset!

Comment: @stars83clouds On my machine, exchanging `\draw` and `\foreach` does the trick.

Comment: @Symbol1 - What make is your machine? I'll go out and buy one! So you suggest putting the for-loop inside the draw statement?

Comment: Yes, as you do not change the setting of `\draw`, letting `\draw` be outside is usually faster.

Comment: @Symbol1 - But that would work for one value, namely 20 degrees, to which I restricted it to in my testing. What if you wished to cycle through multiple values 0, 20, 40, etc? It would not be beneficial to have the `\draw`-statement outside then since only a single `\draw`-execution would be carried out.

Comment: A single `\draw` can draw multiple subpaths. For example `\draw(0,0)--(1,1)(2,2)--(3,3);`.

Comment: I appreciate that. However, if you wished to draw say 20 lines, repeatably writing the clunky formula that I am invoking in the MWE above would make for a considerable task. Is there any way the `\foreach` could be utilized here?

Comment: `\draw[yellow,thin,dashed]foreach\t in{20,40,...,360}{(axis cs: {0.75+0.75*cos(\t)},0,{0.75*sin(\t)})--(axis cs: {0.75+0.75*cos(\t)},{-33.0},{0.75*sin(\t)})};`.

Comment: Thanks @Symbol1! Works like a charm! You missed \ in `\foreach`.

Comment: It is not necessary :)

Comment: @Symbol1 - Now I really do need that make of machine you have. It keeps complaining without the \. Anyway, problem solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is only one argument for the loop you can use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` inside `axis`:

```
  \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{20,40,...,360}{
    \draw[yellow,thin,dashed]
      (axis cs: {0.75+0.75*cos(#1)},0, {0.75*sin(#1)})
      --(axis cs: {0.75+0.75*cos(#1)},{-33.0},{0.75*sin(#1)});
  }
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps,external}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3d,arrows,shapes.geometric}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{150}%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\begin{axis}[
    axis equal,
    axis lines = center,
    width = 16cm,
    height = 16cm,
    xmin=-30,
    xmax=30,
    ymin=-30,
    ymax=30,
    zmin=-30,
    zmax=30,
    view/h=25,
]

  \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{20,40,...,360}{
    \draw[yellow,thin,dashed]
      (axis cs: {0.75+0.75*cos(#1)},0, {0.75*sin(#1)})
      --(axis cs: {0.75+0.75*cos(#1)},{-33.0},{0.75*sin(#1)});
  }

  \draw[yellow,thin,densely dotted] (axis cs: 1.5,-33,0)% lower circle
    \foreach \t in {5,10,...,360}
      {--(axis cs: {0.75+0.75*cos(\t)},-33,{0.75*sin(\t)})}--cycle;

  \draw[yellow,thin,densely dotted] (axis cs: 1.5,0,0)% upper circle
    \foreach \t in {5,10,...,360}
       {--(axis cs: {0.75+0.75*cos(\t)},0,{0.75*sin(\t)})}--cycle;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that `pgfplots` version 1.9 is really old. Current version is 1.14.