# TikZ: groupplot with nested foreach loops to highlight background of profile

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplotstable, loops, groupplots

I'm trying to use `\groupplots` and `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` to generate a dynamic picture showing different profiles. Within those profiles I'd like to highlight different ranges (sequences) with a specific background color.

The sequences are in a separate *.csv file with it's corresponding start/end time and color code. I couldn't get those files loaded, reading each single row and highlight the corresponding range. Nevertheless, most of my code seems to work, since I get a result which is quite close but the inner loop does not seem to work correctly.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{siunitx} % added this line because of marmot's comment
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\RequirePackage{pgfplotstable} % Allows to read tables

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} % Ensure compatibility mode

\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} % Groupplots (multiple x-Axis together)
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds} % Background Library
\usetikzlibrary{calc} % Allows extended coordinate calculations

\newcommand{\tikzsetnextfilename}[1]{\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}
    % externalise TikZ (when not in standalone) - use same filename
    \tikzsetnextfilename{\currfilebase}

    % Data table
    \pgfplotstableset{
        col sep={semicolon}
    }

    \begin{filecontents}{Profile1.csv}
        t_h;I_A;U_V
        0;0;3.584
        0.06905;-0.67;3.53
        0.1381;-0.67;3.514
        0.2072;-0.67;3.5
        0.2762;-0.67;3.484
        0.3453;-0.67;3.466
        0.4143;-0.67;3.448
        0.4834;-0.67;3.428
        0.5524;-0.67;3.412
        0.6215;-0.67;3.399
        0.6905;-0.67;3.385
        0.7596;-0.67;3.369
        0.8287;-0.67;3.35
        0.8977;-0.67;3.321
        0.9668;-0.67;3.275
        1.036;-0.67;3.231
    \end{filecontents}

    \begin{filecontents}{Sequences1.csv}
        tstart_h;tend_h;type
        0.0;0.2762;1
        0.3453;0.6215;2
        0.6905;0.8977;3
        0.9668;1.036;1
    \end{filecontents}

    \begin{filecontents}{Profile2.csv}
        t_h;I_A;U_V
        0;0;3.705
        0.07158;0;3.705
        0.1432;0;3.705
        0.2148;1.675;3.851
        0.2863;1.675;3.892
        0.3579;1.675;3.93
        0.4295;1.675;3.966
        0.5011;1.675;4.001
        0.5727;1.675;4.035
        0.6443;1.675;4.071
        0.7158;1.675;4.11
        0.7874;1.675;4.154
        0.859;1.675;4.196
        0.9306;1.33;4.2
        1.002;1.136;4.2
        1.074;0.9927;4.2
    \end{filecontents}

    \begin{filecontents}{Sequences2.csv}
        tstart_h;tend_h;type
        0.0;0.2148;2
        0.2863;0.5011;1
        0.5727;0.859;2
        0.9306;1.074;3
    \end{filecontents}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \pgfplotsset{
            plot coordinates/math parser=true,
            unbounded coords=jump,
            filter discard warning=false,
        %% Colormap
            colormap={sequencecolors}{
                rgb=(0.75,0,0)
                rgb=(0,0.75,0)
                rgb=(0,0,0.75)
            },
        %% Axis
            scale only axis,
            width=0.8\linewidth,
            height=2cm,
            every axis/.append style={
                line width=1pt,
                tick style={line width=0.8pt},
                grid style={dashed, black!20},
                grid=major,
            },
        %% X-Axis
            xmin=-0.1,
            xmax=1.2,
        }

    %% Primary Y-Axis
        \begin{groupplot}[
            group style={
                group size=1 by 2,
                xlabels at=edge bottom,
                xticklabels at=edge bottom,
                vertical sep=2mm
            },
            tickpos=left,
        %% X-Axis
            xlabel={$t$ in \si{\hour}},
        %% Y-Axis
            ymin=2.4,
            ymax=4.3,
        ]

            \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,2}{
                % Each Profile in seperate groupplot
                \nextgroupplot [ylabel=Seq #1] {
                    % Profile
                    \addplot [color=blue, forget plot] table [x=t_h, y=U_V] {Profile#1.csv};

                    % Seqence
                    \pgfplotstableread{Sequences#1.csv}{\sequences}
                    \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\sequences}
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rows}{\pgfplotsretval-1}

                    \begin{scope} [on background layer]
                        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,\rows}{
                            % Get row from sequences
                            \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{tstart_h}\of{\sequences}\edef\tailTime{\pgfplotsretval}
                            \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{tend_h}\of{\sequences}\edef\headTime{\pgfplotsretval}
                            \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{type}\of{\sequences}\edef\typeColor{\pgfplotsretval}

                            %% This is where the magic should happen, second line is only for debugging, first line does not work properly but what's wrong?
                            % \fill [color of colormap={\typeColor}, opacity=0.1] (\tailTime , \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) rectangle (\headTime, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
                            \fill [color of colormap={#1}, opacity=0.1] ( {#1*0.1}, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) rectangle ( {(#1+1)*0.1}, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
                        }
                    \end{scope}
                }
            }
        \end{groupplot}

    %% Secondary Y-Axis
        \begin{groupplot}[
            group style={
                group size=1 by 2,
                xlabels at=edge bottom,
                xticklabels at=edge bottom,
                vertical sep=2mm,
                y descriptions at=edge right
            },
            grid=none,
            tickpos=right,
        %% X-Axis
            xticklabels={,,},
        %% Y-Axis
            ymin=-6,
            ymax=6,
        ]

        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,2}{
            % Each Profile in seperate groupplot
            \nextgroupplot [ylabel=Seq #1] {
                % Profile
                \addplot [color=red, forget plot] table [x=t_h, y=I_A] {Profile#1.csv};
            }
        }
        \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Results in:

[image: Result of the provided MWE]

With the additional `\fill` command, I get several error message like:

```
filename.tex:149: Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the loating point unit got an ill-formatted floating point number `130.0'. The unreadable part was near '130.0'..
filename.tex:149: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)
```

Doing everything by hand is not possible, the provided data is only a very tiny excerpt of the whole dataset. Is there a way to handle this or do I have to use a seperate column in the profile data which names the color code to handle this any other way?

Comment: If you replace `\si{\hour}` by `\hour`, it works.

Comment: @marmot Thank you for the hint. But this solves not the main problem with the inner loop. Normally I have `siunitx` package loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were two issues. First, the `#1` in the inner loop unfortunately got still "remembered" the `#1` from the outer loop. So I fixed that by hand. Second, and more importantly, `pgfplots` seems to have the ["feature" of postponing expansions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170670/121799), and it expanded the `\fill` command when it already had forgotten the values you read in the inner loop. So I'd propose this code.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{siunitx} % added this line because of marmot's comment
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\RequirePackage{pgfplotstable} % Allows to read tables

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} % Ensure compatibility mode

\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} % Groupplots (multiple x-Axis together)
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds} % Background Library
\usetikzlibrary{calc} % Allows extended coordinate calculations
\newcounter{irun}

\newcommand{\tikzsetnextfilename}[1]{\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}
    % externalise TikZ (when not in standalone) - use same filename
    \tikzsetnextfilename{\currfilebase}
    % Data table
    \pgfplotstableset{
        col sep={semicolon}
    }

    \begin{filecontents}{Profile1.csv}
        t_h;I_A;U_V
        0;0;3.584
        0.06905;-0.67;3.53
        0.1381;-0.67;3.514
        0.2072;-0.67;3.5
        0.2762;-0.67;3.484
        0.3453;-0.67;3.466
        0.4143;-0.67;3.448
        0.4834;-0.67;3.428
        0.5524;-0.67;3.412
        0.6215;-0.67;3.399
        0.6905;-0.67;3.385
        0.7596;-0.67;3.369
        0.8287;-0.67;3.35
        0.8977;-0.67;3.321
        0.9668;-0.67;3.275
        1.036;-0.67;3.231
    \end{filecontents}

    \begin{filecontents}{Sequences1.csv}
        tstart_h;tend_h;type
        0.0;0.2762;1
        0.3453;0.6215;2
        0.6905;0.8977;3
        0.9668;1.036;1
    \end{filecontents}

    \begin{filecontents}{Profile2.csv}
        t_h;I_A;U_V
        0;0;3.705
        0.07158;0;3.705
        0.1432;0;3.705
        0.2148;1.675;3.851
        0.2863;1.675;3.892
        0.3579;1.675;3.93
        0.4295;1.675;3.966
        0.5011;1.675;4.001
        0.5727;1.675;4.035
        0.6443;1.675;4.071
        0.7158;1.675;4.11
        0.7874;1.675;4.154
        0.859;1.675;4.196
        0.9306;1.33;4.2
        1.002;1.136;4.2
        1.074;0.9927;4.2
    \end{filecontents}

    \begin{filecontents}{Sequences2.csv}
        tstart_h;tend_h;type
        0.0;0.2148;2
        0.2863;0.5011;1
        0.5727;0.859;2
        0.9306;1.074;3
    \end{filecontents}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \pgfplotsset{
            plot coordinates/math parser=true,
            unbounded coords=jump,
            filter discard warning=false,
        %% Colormap
            colormap={sequencecolors}{
                rgb=(0.75,0,0)
                rgb=(0,0.75,0)
                rgb=(0,0,0.75)
            },
        %% Axis
            scale only axis,
            width=0.8\linewidth,
            height=2cm,
            every axis/.append style={
                line width=1pt,
                tick style={line width=0.8pt},
                grid style={dashed, black!20},
                grid=major,
            },
        %% X-Axis
            xmin=-0.1,
            xmax=1.2,
        }

    %% Primary Y-Axis
        \begin{groupplot}[
            group style={
                group size=1 by 2,
                xlabels at=edge bottom,
                xticklabels at=edge bottom,
                vertical sep=2mm
            },
            tickpos=left,
        %% X-Axis
            xlabel={$t$ in \si{\hour}},
        %% Y-Axis
            ymin=2.4,
            ymax=4.3,
        ]

            \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,2}{\setcounter{irun}{0}
                % Each Profile in seperate groupplot
                \nextgroupplot [ylabel=Seq #1] {
                    % Profile
                    \addplot [color=blue, forget plot] table [x=t_h, y=U_V] {Profile#1.csv};

                    % Seqence
                    \pgfplotstableread{Sequences#1.csv}{\sequences}
                    \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\sequences}
                    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\rows}{\pgfplotsretval}
                    \typeout{\rows\space rows}

                    \begin{scope} [on background layer]
                        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,\rows}{
                            % Get row from sequences
                            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\theirun}{tstart_h}\of{\sequences}\edef\tailTime{\pgfplotsretval}
                            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\theirun}{tend_h}\of{\sequences}\edef\headTime{\pgfplotsretval}
                            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\theirun}{type}\of{\sequences}\edef\typeColor{\pgfplotsretval}
                            \stepcounter{irun}
                            \typeout{run:\space #1,\space subrun:\space\theirun/\rows:\space\typeColor\space\tailTime\space\headTime}

                            %% This is where the magic should happen, second line is only for debugging, first line does not work properly but what's wrong?
                            \edef\temp{\noexpand\fill [color of
                            colormap=14*\typeColor cm, opacity=0.1] (\tailTime ,
                            \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) rectangle (\headTime,
                            \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});}
                            \temp %from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170670/121799
                            %\fill [color of colormap={#1}, opacity=0.1] ( {#1*0.1}, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) rectangle ( {(#1+1)*0.1}, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
                        }
                    \end{scope}
                }
            }
        \end{groupplot}

    %% Secondary Y-Axis
        \begin{groupplot}[
            group style={
                group size=1 by 2,
                xlabels at=edge bottom,
                xticklabels at=edge bottom,
                vertical sep=2mm,
                y descriptions at=edge right
            },
            grid=none,
            tickpos=right,
        %% X-Axis
            xticklabels={,,},
        %% Y-Axis
            ymin=-6,
            ymax=6,
        ]

        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,2}{
            % Each Profile in seperate groupplot
            \nextgroupplot [ylabel=Seq #1] {
                % Profile
                \addplot [color=red, forget plot] table [x=t_h, y=I_A] {Profile#1.csv};
            }
        }
        \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**: I modified the color command just to double-check that the shading is indeed read. With the original setting, the colors were indistinguishable for ordinary marmot eyes.

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot. Didn't know the `\typeout` command, this is quiet useful for debugging (y)