# Tikz - Coordinates error when using draw with axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, foreach, axis

I am using the following code, which is supposed to cut a function in N parts :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 

\begin{document}
    \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
                [
                    grid,
                    anchor=origin,
                    %axis equal=false,
                    xmin=0,   xmax=1,
                    ymin=0,   ymax=10,
                    minor tick num=1,
                    axis lines = middle,
                    tick label style={inner sep=2pt, font=\footnotesize},
                    %
                    every axis plot post/.append style={thick},
                    samples=500
                ]
                \addplot [domain=0:1, color=blue] {-2*ln(x)};
            \end{axis}

            % Add lines
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\N}{4};

            \foreach \x in {\N,...,0} {
                \draw [line width=0.15mm, red] (\x/\N, 0) -- (\x/\N, 10);
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{document}
```

But, instead of having 5 lines cutting my function from 0 to 1, this is what I have :

[image]

Do you have any idea of why this issue appears ?

P.S : Do you have a better way to declare variables than \pgfmathsetmacro ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The coordinate system of the `axis` is not the same as that of the underlying `tikzpicture`, so when you add a `\draw` outside the `axis` you cannot expect the coordinates to correspond to those inside the `axis`.

Instead, use

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\N}{4};
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{\N,...,0}{ % special looping defined by pgfplots
      \draw [line width=0.15mm, red] (#1/\N, 0) -- (#1/\N, 10);
 }
```

*before* `\end{axis}`.  (Or an `ycomb` plot, as in the example below.)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} % it's recommended to use an explicit version number

\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
                [   
                    width=\columnwidth, % I would generally not use resizebox
                    grid,
                    anchor=origin,
                    %axis equal=false,
                    xmin=0,   xmax=1,
                    ymin=0,   ymax=10,
                    minor tick num=1,
                    axis lines = middle,
                    tick label style={inner sep=2pt, font=\footnotesize},
                    %
                    every axis plot post/.append style={thick},
                    samples=500
                ]
                \addplot [domain=0:1, color=blue] {-2*ln(x)};


            \pgfmathsetmacro{\N}{4};
            \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{\N,...,0}{ % special looping defined by pgfplots
                \draw [line width=0.15mm, red] (#1/\N, 0) -- (#1/\N, 10);
               }

            % alternative: an ycomb plot
            \addplot [line width=0.15mm, red, forget plot, ycomb, samples at={4,...,0}] (x/4,10);
            \end{axis}

        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

(Torbjørn T. has been a bit faster than me...)

The problem is that your `\foreach` loop is run in a place where coordinates don't correspond to what you think. You can try adding:

```latex
\draw[green] (1,0) circle (1pt);
```

after your loop and you should understand that abscissa 1 in the Ti*k*Z `xyz` coordinate system doesn't correspond to abscissa 1 for the plot.

Inside the `axis` environment, however, coordinates use the `axis` coordinate system starting from `pgfplots` compatibility level 1.11. In older compatibility levels, one can use this coordinate system like this: `(axis cs:1,0)` for point `(1,0)` in the `axis` coordinate system. But let's assume for simplicity of the code that we can afford compatibility level 1.11 or later (otherwise, just add two `axis cs:`).

In order to use the `axis` coordinate system to draw your vertical lines, you need to move the `\foreach` loop inside the `axis` environment. This brings a new difficulty, as things inside that environment are often expanded late: see [`\foreach` not behaving in `axis` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170664/foreach-not-behaving-in-axis-environment). Fortunately, both solutions given there work fine. With the simpler solution, the full example becomes:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}% or later

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [ grid,
          anchor=origin,
          %axis equal=false,
          xmin=0,   xmax=1,
          ymin=0,   ymax=10,
          minor tick num=1,
          axis lines = middle,
          tick label style={inner sep=2pt, font=\footnotesize},
          %
          every axis plot post/.append style={thick},
          samples=500 ]
        \addplot [domain=0:1, color=blue] {-2*ln(x)};

        % Add lines (alternatively: \def\N{4}). No semi-colon is needed in
        % either case: these are not TikZ statements.
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\N}{4}

        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach {\N,...,0} {
           \draw[line width=0.15mm, red] (#1/\N, 0) -- (#1/\N, 10);
        }
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As said, there is a second way to write the loop:

```latex
\foreach \x in {\N,...,0} {
   \edef\temp{\noexpand\draw [line width=0.15mm, red]
              (\x/\N, 0) -- (\x/\N, 10);}
   \temp
}
```

Both give the same outcome.

[image: Screenshot]