# Tikzpicture Foreach loop curves not showing up and error in color change

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfmath

In some stackexchange questions, some people posted code in making the code plot the curves iteratively. However, when I try mine, the orange curves do not show up. Here is the code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]\centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \def\Bound{(5*sqrt(2) - sqrt(150 - 100*sqrt(2)))/2}
                %\def\radius{4}
                %\def\startPt{acos( (5+\radius + sqrt((5+\radius)^2 - 50) )/(2*\radius) - 1 )}
                %\def\endPt{acos( (5+\radius - sqrt((5+\radius)^2 - 50) )/(2*\radius) - 1 )}
                \begin{axis}[
                    %xmin=0,xmax=4500,
                    %ymin=0,ymax=0.3,
                    xmin=0,xmax=10,
                    ymin=-5,ymax=5,
                    axis lines=center,
                    axis line style=->, xlabel = {$t$}, ylabel={$V\left(t\right)$},
                    axis equal,
                    legend cell align = {left},
                    every axis y label/.style={at={(0,1)},anchor=south},
                    every axis x label/.style={at={(1,0)},anchor=west},
                    title= {Invariant Set Plots},                   domain=0:15,samples=300,legend pos=outer north east]
                    \addplot [color = blue, thick, domain = -10:10] {x - 5};
                    %\addlegendentry{$V_0 = 0.01$};
                    \addplot [color = red, thick, domain = 0:2*pi] ({\Bound + \Bound*cos(deg(x))}, {\Bound*sin(deg(x))});

                    \foreach \y in {3, 3.5,4,4.5}{
                        \def\radius{\y};
                        \def\startPt{acos( (5+\radius + sqrt((5+\radius)^2 - 50) )/(2*\radius) - 1 )};
                        \def\endPt{acos( (5+\radius - sqrt((5+\radius)^2 - 50) )/(2*\radius) - 1 )};
                        %\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tmp}{100 - \x*20};
                        \addplot[color = orange, thick, domain = \startPt:360-\endPt] ({\radius + \radius*cos(x)}, {\radius*sin(x)});
                    }
                    %\addplot [color = orange, thick, domain = \startPt:360-\endPt] ({\radius + \radius*cos(x)}, {\radius*sin(x)});
                    %\addplot [color = orange, thick, domain = 0:3]{\startPt/360};
                    %\addlegendentry{$V_0 = 0.5$};
                    %\addplot [color = brown, thick, domain = 0:15] {1/(1-(1-1)*exp(-2*x))};
                    %\addlegendentry{$V_0 = 1$};
                    %\addplot [color = orange, thick, domain = 0:15] {1.5/(1.5-(1.5-1)*exp(-2*x))};
                    %\addlegendentry{$V_0 = 1.5$};
                    %\addplot [color = purple, thick, domain = 0:15] {2/(2-(2-1)*exp(-2*x))};
                    %\addlegendentry{$V_0 = 2$};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture} 
            \caption{Optimal Curves.}
        \end{figure}
```

In fact, when I try change the color over each iteration as shown in the code below:

```
    \foreach \x/\y in {0/3, 0.5/3.5, 1/4, 1.5/4.5}{
                        \def\radius{\y};
                        \def\startPt{acos( (5+\radius + sqrt((5+\radius)^2 - 50) )/(2*\radius) - 1 )};
                        \def\endPt{acos( (5+\radius - sqrt((5+\radius)^2 - 50) )/(2*\radius) - 1 )};
                        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\tmp}{100 - \x*20};
                        \addplot[color = orange!\tmp!yellow, thick, domain = \startPt:360-\endPt] ({\radius + \radius*cos(x)}, {\radius*sin(x)});
                    }
```

I even get an error message saying that it's an `Undefined control sequence` at the `\end{axis}` command.

Does anybody know what is going on with the code?

Comment: This is a classic, see for instance [\foreach not behaving in axis environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170664/foreach-not-behaving-in-axis-environment) and [my answer to “Tikz - Coordinates error when using draw with axis”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/501524/73317). Replace your three `\def` with `\edef` and it works (but you didn't provide a minimal working example, not good!).

Comment: Hello, sorry for the very late reply, but I just wanted to put arrows in even intervals in the plots.

Comment: Hello, I spent 10 minutes for the second time adding all the missing code to your example (`\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}`, etc.), fixing the broken loop and trying to understand what you want. And this is quite a different question. Please ask it as such, in a *new question*, with a minimal example that compiles without error (I told you how), with decent formatting (the above code has so many spaces on the left that it is unreadable for me), and please explain *much more clearly* what you want.

Comment: You can provide a hand drawing (or use Paint or a similar program on top of a screenshot of what you already have) to show people how these arrows should look like, and where they should be. Thank you on behalf of your future readers. :-)