# Drawing multiple arrows between two given points with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I need to draw some arrows between two given points in my diagram. I want to turn the shorter arrow into four smaller ones and the longer one into seven, all joined together. How can I draw them automatically between the given coordinates?

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
    myarrow/.style={-{Triangle[length=1.5mm,width=1.5mm]}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
   every axis plot post/.style={mark=-,thick,mark size=10mm},
   xtick style={draw=none},
   xticklabels={,,},
   xmin=-0.9,
   xmax=1.1,
   ymin=15,
   ymax=20,
   cycle list name=black white,
   only marks, 
   x=2cm, y=1cm,
   every node near coord/.append style={font=\small,yshift=-2.5mm,xshift=\myshift}
 ]
\addplot [nodes near coords={\labelz},
visualization depends on={value \thisrowno{2}\as\labelz},visualization depends on={value \thisrowno{3}\as\myshift}] 
table[header=false] {
0 15.183 a 15mm
0 18.300 b 15mm
0 19.011 c 15mm
};
\draw[draw=blue,myarrow,very thick] (0.25,18.300) -- (0.25,15.183);
\draw[draw=blue,myarrow,very thick] (-0.25,18.300) -- (-0.25,19.011);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Expected result for the shorter arrow:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "all joined together"? Could you please provide a hand-drawn sketch of what you're expecting?

Comment: I don't know if I get the question right, but cannot you superimpose them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ti*k*Z has a function to invoke a command multiple times. It's called with  `\foreach \i in {1,...,10}{ do something }`. Unfortunately, inside the `axis` environment, [this function has some problems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170664/foreach-not-behaving-in-axis-environment), thus the use of `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,10}{ do something }` is encouraged.

Using this as a starting point, I calculated an increment for your arrows, *e.g.* `(18.300-15.183)/\largeArrowParts`. This will automatically calculate how long each segment should be, based on the `\largeArrowParts` number that you can define. In this case, it's set to `8`.

I then use this increment to draw `\largeArrowParts`-many arrows starting at your starting point and moving forward using the index of the `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` function.

This will, in fact, stack the arrows on top of each other, and each arrow will start at the starting point; thus, the first arrow is only shorter than the second one, etc. This has two advantages:

1. It's much easier to code.
2. It results in one solid line with arrowheads, whereas single arrows of the increment length would segment the line, which doesn't look nice.

#### Code

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{
    myarrow/.style = {-{Triangle[length = 1.5mm, width = 1.5mm]}}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            every axis plot post/.style = {
                mark = -,
                thick,
                mark size = 10mm
            },
            xtick style = {
                draw = none
            },
            xticklabels = {,,},
            xmin = -0.9,
            xmax = 1.1,
            ymin = 15,
            ymax = 20,
            cycle list name = black white,
            only marks, 
            x = 2cm,
            y = 1cm,
            every node near coord/.append style = {
                font = \small,
                yshift = -2.5mm, xshift = \myshift
            }
        ]
        
            \addplot [
                nodes near coords = {\labelz},
                visualization depends on = {%
                    value \thisrowno{2}\as\labelz%
                },
                visualization depends on = {%
                    value \thisrowno{3}\as\myshift%
                }
            ] table[header=false] {
                0 15.183 a 15mm
                0 18.300 b 15mm
                0 19.011 c 15mm
            };
            
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\smallArrowParts}{4}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\largeArrowParts}{8}
            
            \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,\largeArrowParts}{
                \pgfmathsetmacro{\largeInc}{(18.300-15.183)/\largeArrowParts}
                \draw [
                    draw = blue,
                    myarrow,
                    very thick
                ] (0.25, 18.300) -- (0.25, {18.300 - #1 * \largeInc});
            }
            
            \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,\smallArrowParts}{
               \pgfmathsetmacro{\smallInc}{(19.011-18.300)/\smallArrowParts}
                \draw [
                    draw = blue,
                    myarrow,
                    very thick
                ] (-0.25, 18.300) -- (-0.25, {18.300 + #1 * \smallInc});
            }

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image: Plot]